# What is meant by a "$S$-strictly diagonally dominant matrix" in the book 'Geršgorin and His Circles'

Tags: linear-algebra

What is meant by a "$S$-strictly diagonally dominant matrix" in the book *Geršgorin and His Circles.*

The definition of [strictly diagonally dominant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) is easy to find, but the definition of  "$S$-strictly diagonally dominant matrix"  is needed.

Comment: Can you work to improve the English in this a bit? It's not very comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{i=1, \, j=1}^{n,n}$ is called strictly diagonally dominant if $|a_{ii}| \gt \sum_{j=1, \, j\neq i}^n |a_{ij}|$ for each $i$. In words, for each row the diagonal entry is in absolute value larger than the sum of the absolute values of all other entries in the same row.

The "strictly" refers to the inequality being "strict."

Now, for a subset $S \subset \{1, \dots, n\}$ one calls the matrix $S$-strictly diagonally dominant if

- $|a_{ii}|> r_i^S(A)$ for all $i \in S$ and
- $(|a_{ii}-r_i^S(A))(|a_{jj}|-r_j^{\overline{S}}(A))>  r_i^{\overline{S}}(A)r_j^S(A)$ for all $i \in S$ and $j \in \overline{S}$

where  $r_i^T(A)= \sum_{j \in T, \, j \neq i}|a_{ij}| $ and $\overline{S}$ is the compleemnt of $S$.

The special case $S= \{1, \dots, n \}$ yields the first definition.

The relevance of this notion is that it is weaker than strictly diagonally dominant (every SSD matrix is $S$-SSD for every $S$), yet it still allows to derive some of the same conclusions on the matrix.

An example of a matrix that is $\{1,2\}$-SSD yet not SSD is:

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 2.6 & -0.4 & -0.7 & -0.2 \\
-0.4 & 2.6 & -0.5 & -0.7 \\
-0.6 & -0.7 & 2.2 & -1.0 \\
-0.8 & -0.7 & -0.5 & 2.2  
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
taken from Bru,  Pedroche,  Szyld  "Subdirect sums of S-strictly diagonally dominant matrices."

Comment: Thank you for help,I know definition but I need examples for this matrix to understand what is mean *S*

Comment: I am not sure what you mean bu "what is mean S" The $S$ can be any subset. I will include an examle though.

Comment: How I can write S-strictly diagonally domainant  in Matlab?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know what you mean precisely. Do you want a function that tests this is Matlab or do you want to create such matrices in Matlab. Either way I cannot answer. With Matlab questions you might have more luck on [scicomp.se]

Comment: I want a function that tests this in matlab pleas

Comment: Sorry I cannot answer this. You could ask a new questions, here, or possibly on the site I linked to for asking this.